# how to stack components from bottom up instead of top down in defined grid container?

Tags: css, grid

I am creating templates using grids and object oriented css. The goal is to separate components from containers. The challenge i run into is that in header and footer container i would like that components are stacked from bottom up instead of top down.

For example

```
    <div class="gridX gridY" id ="Footer container">   
      <div id = "links component"></div>   
      <div id="copyright component"></div>   
    <div>
```

In the example the requirement is that 'copyright component' has to be at the bottom of the footer container(which is the page) following other components stacked on top. Right now the only way i know how to do is by keep components height fixed which enables me to calculate the position of each component that way positing as needed making it work from top to bottom, however. This way it goes against the goal of oocss - being able to swap components in the layout while having height flexible

display:table -> display:table-cell with vertical-align:bottom is not working in IE, so this solutions is not applicable in our case.

I am new to grids and oocss, perhaps, i am missing some understanding.

how to stack components from bottom up instead of top down in defined grid container?

Thank you,
Margots

Comment: Did you try reversing your HTML? Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Hunter, that sounds like what i am looking. How do i reverse the float in html from bottom up?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a top-down technology.

The height can be flexible. Use `min-height:` and let content grow naturally.

Don't resort to using tables for layout. CSS can do everything you need.

Comment: I don't know if min-height will be solution because # of components inserted into the footer container will change

Comment: Don't worry, that's the whole purpose of min-height.